# Grab files changed by commit from GitHub API

Tags: git, github, github-api

I am trying to use the GitHub API to grab all files changed by a particular commit, but I don't see a good way of doing it.

In other words, whats the equivalent of `git show --name-only sha1` in the GitHub API?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you fetch the commit via the Repository Commits API, the response will include a `files` array with the list of changed files:

https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#get-a-single-commit

Comment: This doesn't seem to still be the case.  When I put in my URL https://api.github.com/repos/doitcwd-nwhack/sailsweb/git/commits/731f1a20993f474ab496c4ec506ae63030d1aa41 I don't get anything after "parents"

Comment: @MattWestlake You're using the wrong URL -- that's not the API endpoint I linked to in my answer. Try this: https://api.github.com/repos/doitcwd-nwhack/sailsweb/commits/731f1a20993f474ab496c4ec506ae63030d1aa41

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/commits#get-a-commit

Comment: @IvanZuzak any change in Github Api ? **files** field is no more available in this service.  Example : https://api.github.com/repos/debonil/get-started-python/commits